# Can't Change Password in VB.net using Ms Access Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE tbl_users SET [Password] = '" & txtNewPass.Text & "' Where Username = '" & txtUsser.Text & "'", con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtNewPass.Text
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("Password Changse Successfully!")
                  txtOldPass.Text = ""
                  txtNewPass.Text = ""
                  txtConfPass.Text = ""
                  txtUsser.Text = ""
 End If
```

Please help me. I try to change the existing password although the msgbox prompt that I have been successfully change the password it doesn't change at all. I also checked the database but the password still doesn't change.

Comment: It looks like you're not executing the command.

Comment: i just forgot to include "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()" on my code. :) thanks for the help. it's working now..